# Extracting images urls from html in c# using html agility pack and writing them in a xml file

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, xml

I am new to c# and I really need help with the following problem. I wish to extract the photos urls from a webpage that have a specific pattern. For example I wish to extract all the images that have the following pattern name_412s.jpg. I use the following code to extract images from html, but I do not kow how to adapt it.

```
public void Images()
    {
        WebClient x = new WebClient();
        string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.Load(source);

        foreach(HtmlNode link in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img")
        {
          images[] = link["src"];
       }
}
```

I also need to write the results in a xml file. Can you also help me with that?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the query results, you need to add a condition to your XPath.  For instance, `//img[contains(@src, 'name_412s.jpg')]` will limit the results to only `img` elements that have an `src` attribute that contains that file name.

As far as writing out the results to XML, you'll need to create a new XML document and then copy the matching elements into it.  Since you won't be able to directly import an HtmlAgilityPack node into an XmlDocument, you'll have to manually copy all the attributes.  For instance:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

// ...

public void Images()
{
    WebClient x = new WebClient();
    string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.Load(source);
    XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement imgElements = output.CreateElement("ImgElements");
    output.AppendChild(imgElements);
    foreach(HtmlNode link in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[contains(@src, '_412s.jpg')]")
    {
        XmlElement img = output.CreateElement(link.Name);
        foreach(HtmlAttribute a in link.Attributes)
        {
            img.SetAttribute(a.Name, a.Value)
        }
        imgElements.AppendChild(img);
    }
    output.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
}
```

Comment: Well I need to identify all the images on the page that have _412s.jpg in their name and I want to add them in a xml, so , later, I can read the xml list and display the links. I want to extract all elements, not only one. There are hundreds of images with _412s.jpg in their name. How can I do that? and which is the best method to write the xml so I can display the photos later, when reading the xml file?

Comment: @CristinaUrsu See my updated answer, hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: do you know how to adapt the code for windows 8? I have read about fizzler html agility pack but I can't figure it out. It does not recognize WebClient x = new WebClient(); or XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument(); or out.Save(@"C:\test.xml");. Can you help me?

Comment: As far as the `out.save(...)` line, that was just a typo.  It was supposed to be `output.save(...)`.  I fixed the example.  As far as the other two lines go, they assume that you are importing the correct namespaces.  `WebClient` is in the `System.Net` namespace, and `XmlDocument` is in the `System.Xml` namespace.  So at the top of the code file, you need to add those two `using` statements, I have added those to the example as well.  No adaptation for Windows 8 should be necessary, as far as I know.